# How to write artisan command to search for specific routes name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-artisan

I'm writing command for Laravel to search for a specific route pattern.

I created command with argument {route} which execute bash command and echo the result.

```
protected $signature = 'routes:find {route}';

  public function handle()
    {
        echo  exec('php artisan route:list | grep '.$this->argument('route'));
    }
```

the problem is this command output the routes in one line and does not offer any formatting like default `route:list` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you `exec` that command, it won't work in Windows. Also it is not guaranteed that the `grep` command is present as well.

Why don't you go after the original `route:list` command implementation?

If you check `RouteListCommand.php` file (search it in your `vendor` directory), you'll find a better way to search for a route, starting from this

```
public function __construct(Router $router)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->router = $router;
    $this->routes = $router->getRoutes();
}
```

The right approach is to delegate the `Illuminate\Routing\Router` object to provide routes for you.